# Converting Archimesh to standard Blender objects

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode, archimesh-add-on

I initially used Archimesh to create a house plan, including windows. I have since decided that these are difficult to manipulate and have gone back to using native Blender tools. However, some of the windows are as I want them visually so I decided to remove these from the WIndow Groups (that Archimesh assigns) and use these as individual objects.

One thing I noticed was that these could not be manipulated in Object mode (such as rotate, move, scale, etc) and I could only carry out these actions in Edit mode, with the whole mesh selected.

Has anybody else come across a situation where objects are not behaving as objects in this way? And if so, can these be converted into correct Objects? I have tried convert to mesh but this did not change how they behaved.

[image: Object mode - cannot move][image: Edit mode - can move]

Comment: On the first picture (top middle) you can see little padlocks near the transforms. You have to open them.

Comment: Thanks. I had never even noticed those. Everything I have created myself has clearly had these automatically unlocked but I guess Archimesh locks them as it has its own resizing process. Cheers. That sorted it.